# What to expect in the Sales Cloud exam?

Tags: certification, sales-cloud

This is a spin-off from [my old question which helped my pass the first stage of the Advanced Developer exam last month](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8433/how-to-study-prepare-for-the-salesforce-advanced-developer-certification).

Similar to Mohit's answer for the above question,

1. What would be the key topics of the Sales Cloud exam?
2. What key topics are likely to have been recently added?

The target audience of this question would,

1. Be requesting to only know the key topics as a simple list.
2. Already have a few years' experience with Salesforce development.

Needless to say, but just for the sake of completeness, [the exam guide's *Section 4 Recommended Training and References* and *Section 5 Exam Outline*](http://certification.salesforce.com/SG_CertifiedSalesCloudConsultant.pdf?v=20&v=13&SiteID=0DMG00000008Po7) are considerably broad.

Comment: FWIW, it's intentionally overly broad. Most people won't study something if they know it won't be on the test...

Comment: Just browse through the following link...it has already listed out topics to study and type of questions: http://sfdctrail.com/2016/02/05/salesforce-sales-cloud-certification-tips/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sales cloud examination ,you will need to put your consultant hat .The first and foremost thing that you should be aware of is "Typical Sales Cycle".Right from campaigning to opportunity closure you should understand the process and map business process to the salesforce modules .Here are some of the key topics that have been tutoring lot of folks to pass this examination

**1. Multicurrency**

understanding multicurrency limitations and offerings .Use the below document for reference

https://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_using_multiple_currencies.pdf

**2. Lead Management**

Understand whats lead scoring ,how leads are captured in salesforce,Lead Assignment rules ,Importance of lead source,lead conversion process

**3.Campaign Management**

Data model supported by salesforce,key campaign fields,campaign members ,how to calculate ROI from the campaign,campaign management ROI metrics ,measuring parameters like no of opened mails ,click rate

**4.Account Management**

Distinguish person and Business Account ,Define Contact Role,Understand Account Team

**5.Opportunity Management**

Understand Sales Stages ,Importance of Sales Team,Adding Products to Opportunity,understand how to calculate revenue ,understand scheduling like quantity,revenue or both

**6.Forecasting**

Differentiate collaborative and customisable forecasting,How product ,revenue schedule affect forecasting ,standard reports available for forecasting,forecast hierarchy,Forecasting and opportunity association

**7.Territory Management**

Proper use case to implement territory management ,Decision tree to decide whether Territory management will beneficial for Organisation

**8.Order Management**

This is typically new to salesforce with just year ahead and you can expect some questions

**9.Quote Management**

Quote objects provided by salesforce ,keeping quote line items sync with opportunity line items .

**10.Data.com and Work.com overview**

understand definitions and overview only

**11.Salesforce for outlook and Salesforce to Salesforce**

Watch youtube videos around same .

**12.Chatter as a collaboration tool and how it helps to improve sales collaboration among reps .**

**13. Differentiate between Content Management and Chatter files .**

Explore concepts of library and Content Delivery

**14.Sharing rules and how this differs from territory management engine**

**15.General understanding of Key KPI metrics for a sales manager to draft reports and infer performance of sales reps**

**16.Concept of Fiscal quarter and forecast reports based on fiscal quarter**

Refer help and Training for content on this topics and also try to implement in a demo org to see how practically these work.

Comment: _"Sales cloud examination, you will need to put your consultant hat."_ Thanks Mohit yet once again for the key points. I just passed.

Comment: Congradulations !!! What more can i say ....See my location change update so my time zone of providing answers will also change :)