# where can i found salesforce latest dumps for dev 401 exam

Tags: certification, dev401

I would like to know the study plan  of Certification (401). can you help me the sites to download the dumps.

Answer (score 0):

[Here are some example questions](http://quizlet.com/45873687/salesforce-dev-401-exam-study-guide-courtesy-of-john-hogan-via-adam-frank-flash-cards/) but make sure you read the official documentation to get yourself prepared. I don't think you'll find actual exam dumps, but a lot of questions are the same, if not similar to what you find online. Just use google, he's your best friend!

Also go through the [Study Guide](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcertification.salesforce.com%2FSG_CertifiedDeveloper.pdf&ei=NRQJVPPDHtK2uAT-9oHQCg&usg=AFQjCNGZJe6UYBlXcPIpLoNjbN4tzWAFzQ&sig2=2XrLGaZv4N8v1JuzH0prCg&bvm=bv.74649129,d.c2E&cad=rja) for more detailed explanation of what the exam will look like.

And [this is another question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7983/how-to-study-prepare-for-the-salesforce-developer-certification) asked previously on this site regarding how to prepare.