# Where can I get the material for Salesforce Certified Administrator (WI15) exam?

Tags: administration, certification

I am planing to give **WI15** Exam within this week.

As preparation alone not sufficient for the exam I need MOCK exam papers for Administrator - WI15 which will help me to clear this exam.

If you have MOCK Exam papers for Administrator - WI15, please provide me.

Any one can guide me as how and what to prepare for **Salesforce Administrator - WI15** certification exam

Any imp links / pdfs etc.. any one can please share

Many Thanks

Comment: Personally, I think that if you aren't sure where the resources are to study for the exam, you're probably not ready for it.  This isn't google and asking for mock exams is likely going to get your question closed. There have been succesfull certification questions, consider updating your question in similar fashion for 201 ,  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7983/how-to-study-prepare-for-the-salesforce-developer-certification

Answer (score 7):

Rather than asking for mock exams/ dumps, you should refer the [Official Guide](http://certification.salesforce.com/SG_CertifiedAdministrator.pdf) and try to learn the new concepts. SFSE is a place for getting community help for your technical queries, not for shortcuts to "help me clear the exam".

Answer (score 2):

Hello Jaimin,
              first Best of luck for your certification exam. For Admin exam you follow salesforce admin study material form this link:   http://certification.salesforce.com/administrators
And for Mock Exam you follow these links 
http://www.sfdc99.com/2014/10/02/guide-to-passing-all-salesforce-certifications/
Again Best of luck.
Thanks,
Pritam Shekhawat