# Accessing salesforce data from a VS console app

Tags: rest-api, data, connected-apps, .net

Ok I have a really basic question. I'm am still very confused trying to use this platform. So I'm asking those types of questions that would not be well received on Stack Overflow. I want to become a productive member of this site, so please bear with me while I'm in the fog.

I have a VS C# console app, and I have used a connected service to link it with salesforce.

[image]

[image]

Now I am feeling like an absolute idiot, as I am not sure what I can do with that connection. I also have the added complication of not having a sandbox.

So my first question is:

1. Do I need to use sandbox to develop my apps?

When I run the app I have this:

[image]

Now I'm wondering if I'm able to login to my salesforce account from the console line and access data. I just can't figure out how to make that connection. I understand that I can use an external database.. but I am assuming I can access the dummy data that salesforce supplies.

How can I actually access my salesforce data from the app?

I don't expect a detailed answer, just if someone is able to point me in the right direction. Salesforce has so many features, it's actually difficult for me to ascertain which ones I need to follow. Looking at this answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/7989/25387 I think I'm a 2.99 lol.

I'm mainly concerned with .net development and salesforce at this stage.

*I added the VS to the title so not to be confused with salesforce console.*
*Thanks.*

Comment: Have you reviewed : https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_overview.htm - Connected Apps (the UI piece in SF, not the whole app) simply provide a means for authentication and access control. Once you are authenticated, you use the SOAP / REST api to access what you need in SF so review those docs.

Comment: There is the Salesforce CLI which allows you to connect to Salesforce from the command prompt. "Salesforce Trailhead" is a great place to learn general Salesforce. You don't need a sandbox but I would create a sandbox just in case you do something wrong! and doesnt take long to create. At least with a sandbox you know you can't break anything. You can go the oAuth route, depends what your app is doing. Have you seen: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Integrating_Force.com_with_Microsoft_.NET

Comment: @Francis THANK YOU! I don't why I didn't find that, I've been scouring the site... it just takes time.. I need to upgrade my edition to get a sandbox.. Please feel free to draft your comment as a ans answer, as it's good.

Comment: @Eric yes I have seen that, but it wasn't gelling with me.. I think the other link is a good starting point and I've been listening to the pluralsight talks on .net, and doing some trailforce projects..++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding the Salesforce Connected Services to a .NET console application you have a couple of things:

1. It will have brought in the [Force.com .NET toolkit](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET) from nuget
2. It will have created a Connected App for you in the org that you entered credentials for in the wizard.
3. Optionally used T4 templates to generate entity classes for you in a Models folder.

To actually establish a Salesforce session in the console app you can use the AuthenticationClient. Sample based off [the SimpleConsole application](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/blob/master/samples/SimpleConsole/Program.cs).

E.g.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = RunSample();
        task.Wait();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async Task RunSample()
    {
        var auth = new AuthenticationClient();
        await auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, Username, Password);
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to Salesforce");

        var client = new ForceClient(auth.InstanceUrl, auth.AccessToken, auth.ApiVersion);

        Console.WriteLine("Get Accounts");

        const string qry = "SELECT ID, Name FROM Account";
        var accts = new List<Account>();
        var results = await client.QueryAsync<Account>(qry);
        var totalSize = results.totalSize;

        Console.WriteLine("Queried " + totalSize + " records.");

        accts.AddRange(results.records);

    }
```

This excludes all sorts of error handling that you need, but it shows how to get connected and then make a basic SOQL query.

The `ConsumerKey`, `ConsumerSecret`, `Username`, and `Password` were all read from the App.config. The Consumer* fields you can get as per [How to Get consumer Key and consumer Secret from Salesforce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353442/54026)

You can make all your CRUD calls via the ForceClient class.

The example above was run against a developer edition org. The main difference with a sandbox would be changing the URL that AuthenticationClient uses.

Comment: I've CONNECTED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! yeh :)